# Saving 3 dimensional array to a file in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I want to save a 3 dimensional arrays values to a txt or csv file in python.
dCx, dCy

I  used:

```
numpy.savetxt('C:/Users/musa/Desktop/LOCO_All_tests/FODO_Example/AllQ/dCx.csv',dCx,delimiter=',')
numpy.savetxt('C:/Users/musa/Desktop/LOCO_All_tests/FODO_Example/AllQ/dCy.csv',dCy,delimiter=',')
```

And to load it again:

```
dCx = numpy.genfromtxt('C:/Users/musa/Desktop/LOCO_All_tests/FODO_Example/AllQ/dCx.csv', delimiter=',')
dCy = numpy.genfromtxt('C:/Users/musa/Desktop/LOCO_All_tests/FODO_Example/AllQ/dCy.csv', delimiter=',')
```

But i got the error massage

"Expected 1D or 2D array, got 3D array instead"

Si i wanted to change the 3d arrays first to 2 arrays and then save it to the files, and when uploaded again i convert it back to 3d for example:

```
dCx2 = np.array(dCx).reshape(np.array(dCx).shape[0], -1)
dCy2 = np.array(dCy).reshape(np.array(dCy).shape[0], -1)
```

and after loaded to variable named dCx3 and dCy3 i used:

```
dCx = np.array(dCx3).reshape(
    np.array(dCx3).shape[0], np.array(dCx3).shape[1] // np.array(dCx).shape[2], np.array(dCx).shape[2])

#dCy = np.array(dCy3).reshape(
#    np.array(dCy3).shape[0], np.array(dCy3).shape[1] // np.array(dCy).shape[2], np.array(dCy).shape[2])
```

I am looking for a better method that i can used in the saving the 3d arrays to file, or a method to convert the 2d into 3d without having to measure the original arrays every time as it is used in this line:

```
 np.array(dCy).shape[2], np.array(dCy).shape[2])
```

Comment: The CSV format is inherently tabular format; it is not suitable for three dimensional data.

Comment: Are you doing anything with the files in between saving them to disk, and reading them back into memory/NumPy again?

Comment: @9769953 No, the files are not touched

Comment: Why not use `numpy.save(filepath, data)` and `data = numpy.load(filepath)`? These are binary file formats, and generic for any type of NumPy data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`numpy.save(filepath, data)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) and [`data = numpy.load(filepath)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.load.html).

These are binary file formats, and generic for any type of NumPy data

Answer (score 0):

Try tofile. it works for in my case. but array will write in 1D

```
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(0,21).reshape(7,3)
arr.tofile('file.txt',sep=',')
arr2=np.fromfile('file.txt',sep=',')
```

Comment: it works but as you mentioned the arrays will return in 1 D so still the same problem

Comment: in that case iterate over every row, and append to the file.\n
import numpy as np
arr=np.arange(0,21).reshape(7,3)
print(arr)
for i in arr:
    with open('file.txt','a') as fp:
        fp.write(str(i))
        fp.write("\n")